# change the flex properties of a DOM object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, flexbox

I have a very simple div in my DOM. I want to add a style property to this div element using JavaScript.

my element is selected like so:

```
const firstBlock = document.getElementById('box1')
```

just for the sake of testing things out I kept it super simple and just tried this:

```
firstBlock.style.display= "flex : 4"
```

but this does not add anything to the class linked to the element...

any idea how to do this very simply?

and I just tried:

```
firstBlock.style.flexGrow= 6
```

which adds the flex-grow property of 6, but it's not working on the screen...

Comment: `"flex : 4"` isn’t a valid value for the [`display` property](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) (as confirmed by `CSS.supports("display", "flex : 4")` resulting in `false`). What do you expect it to do?

Comment: "but this does not add anything to the class linked to the element.",. No it won't, its meant only to alter the inline style of an element.

Comment: iye si just found this out while fiddling with all the properties, what i wan tis my box to change size when i type in the new flex value in an input field

Comment: Right-click and inspect your element. Look at the applied styles. Is your style applied? Are you sure your element is a flex item, i.e. a child of a `display: flex` element? Does a _fixed_ `flex-grow: 6;` in your style sheet (as opposed to a dynamic property set in your script) actually set the correct style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax for changing style for a property is -

`document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style`

You are trying to set "display: flex: 4" in it.

Instead try -
`document.getElementById(id).style.flex = 4`